# MySQL+GDal+MapServer+OpenLayers Web Mercator problem

Tags: coordinate-system, openlayers-2, gdal, wms, mapserver

I have a problem/question what is the most efficient way to go from WGS84 (EPSG:4326) to Web Mercator.

Outline of the structure right now:

1. **MySQL Database**: with point Latitude/Longitude Data [~200 million points] these points I bin myself with a SQL query, right now I just bin them with (I insert into separate table for convenience):

   ```
   SELECT 
       (FLOOR((longitude/100000)/(360/(POWER(2,16))))*(360/(POWER(2,16)))) AS pixel_X,     
       (FLOOR((latitude/100000)/(180/(POWER(2,15))))*(180/(POWER(2,15)))) AS pixel_Y,
       count(*) AS Amount
       FROM PointData
       GROUP BY pixel_X, pixel_Y
       ORDER BY pixel_X ASC, pixel_Y ASC;
   ```

   I think this should give me a raster in EPSG:4326.
   This is where I think would be the best place to introduce a change to bin into EPSG:3857 (Web Mercator, EPSG:900913).

   I bin the information here because it's impossible to send 200-300 million points to GDAL so I have to give up some correctness.
2. **GDAL_grid** that creates a raster img-file from the data in the database (the DBConnection.vrt is just a database connection).

   ```
   gdal_grid -of HFA -a nearest:radius1=0.0054931640625:radius2=0.0054931640625 -outsize 65536 32768 -l layer DBConnection.vrt Rasters/output.img --config GDAL_NUM_THREADS ALL_CPUS
   ```

   Right now this creates an image in EPSG:4326. The nearest algorithm is used to keep the binned raster from MySQL as unchanged as possible.
3. **MapServer** reading the img raster

   ```
    MAP
           NAME "TestMap"
           PROJECTION
               "init=epsg:4326"
           END
           STATUS OFF
           EXTENT -180 -90 180 90
           UNITS DD
           SHAPEPATH "./layers"
           WEB
               IMAGEPATH "/ms4w/tmp/ms_tmp/"
               IMAGEURL "/ms_tmp/"
               METADATA
                   "wms_title" "Test Server"
                   "wms_onlineresource" "http://localhost/cgi-bin/mapserv?map=/ms4w/apps/TestMaps/TestMap.map&"
                   "wms_enable_request" "*"
               END
           END         
           [...]   
           LAYER
               NAME TestLayer
               STATUS OFF
               TYPE RASTER
               DATA "Rasters\output.img"
               METADATA
                   "wms_title" "output"
                   "wms_transparent" "true"
               END
               PROJECTION
                   "init=epsg:4326"
               END
               CLASSITEM "pixel"
               PROCESSING "SCALE=0,1000"
               PROCESSING "SCALE_BUCKETS=100"
               CLASS
                   [...] (just some coloring to give a makeshift heatmap)
               END
           END
       END
   ```
4. **OpenLayers** connects to MapServer and shows the map in the browser.

   ```
    function init() {
       map = new OpenLayers.Map("Map", {
               [...]
           ]
       });
       [...]
       var TestLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
           "TestLayer", 
           "http://localhost/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?map=/ms4w/apps/TestMaps/TestMap.map", 
           {layers: 
               'TestLayer',
               transparent: 'true'
           }, {
               isBaseLayer:false,
               visibility: true
           }
       );
       [...]
   ```

So at this point the maps show up fine in a EPSG:4326 projection, no problem at all, I have EPSG:4326 country polygons that I use as a base layer right now.

[image: Result in epsg:4326]
The problem is I would like to have a Web Mercator map, street map and so on, but I can't get the projection to change.

So far I've tried:

- changing the Projection "init:epsg:4326" in MapServer to epsg:3857 but to no avail, the layers are not recognized by open layers any more and I just get picture not received error.
- using gdal_warp on the output.img and change to epsg:3857, didn't work either, same problem, also this is really time inefficient because warp takes forever and I might as well put it into the right projection right away in the database or in the GDAL_GRID.

I have probably been misunderstanding projections and GIS terms so if so let me know, this is the first time I do anything like this, only worked with the Google Maps API before with small amounts of Lat/Lng points where you just send the Lat/Lng to Google and it does the rest.

I tried to include as much information as I could, if anything is missing or unclear let me know.